# MYSQL Update random selection of X records

Tags: mysql, random, sql-update

I have a table of students (called students), this table has a char field called SchoolLevel indicating what level they are in (H -> "high", M -> "middle" E -> "elementary").  I would like to randomly assign students in each level to respective schools with an int field called 'schoolID'.  So for example, if I have 4530 elementary students

schoolID=1, should be assigned to 3000 random 'E' students

schoolID=2, should be assigned to another 530 random 'E' students

and schoolID=3 should be assigned to the remaining unassigned 1000 records ('E' students).

I tried to do something like this:

update students
set SchoolID = 1
where SchoolLevel=(Select SchoolLevel from students where SchoolLevel='E' order by RAND() limit 300)

That clearly does not work - apparently you cannot specify the target table as the same table for update in the FROM clause.   Can I even do what I am trying to do, i.e., update a random selection of X records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way (assuming that `SchoolID` initially `IS NULL`)

```sql
UPDATE students
   SET SchoolID = 1 
 WHERE SchoolLevel = 'E'
   AND SchoolID IS NULL
 ORDER BY RAND()
 LIMIT 3000;
```

Then

```sql
UPDATE students
   SET SchoolID = 2 
 WHERE SchoolLevel = 'E'
   AND SchoolID IS NULL
 ORDER BY RAND()
 LIMIT 530;
```

and so on

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/202e8/1)** example